# The right usage of braces within arrow function within Array.prototype.filter

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

```
(function (){
  console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].filter(i => {i % 2 == 0}));
})();
// Array[]
```

I want to print an array that contains only even numbers, that is 0 and 2 in the case above. Array.prototype.filter along with an arrow function are used for this purpose.

The above code returns an empty array. However, if I remove braces, the code works as expected.

```
(function (){
  console.log([0, 1, 2, 3].filter(i => i % 2 == 0));
})();
// Array[0, 2]
```

Can someone explain why it happens? I always used arrow functions with braces and they worked just fine but it seems to me that there are caveats.

Comment: Read about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#the_arrow_function_expression).

Answer (score 2):

The body of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax) is either an expression, whose value is the value returned by the function, or a block of statements, similar to a regular function.

`i => i % 2 == 0` has an expression as the body and is equivalent to:

```js
function(i) {
  return i % 2 == 0
}
```

`i => { i % 2 == 0 }` has a block of statements as the body and is equivalent to:

```js
function(i) {
  i % 2 == 0
}
```

It does not return anything. Therefore [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) concludes that none of the array items matches the filter and returns `[]`.

If you wrap the arrow function body in curly braces you have to explicitly mention what it returns:

```js
i => { return i % 2 == 0 }
```

This is equivalent to `i => i % 2 == 0` and not worth using.
However, if the arrow function does many things and an expression cannot be used then the block of statements and the explicit `return` are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions can skip the `return` keyword for single-line functions.

If you add braces, it means that the function will have multiple lines and it needs to know when to return something. Therefore, you need to add a `return` statement.

The explicit (with braces) equivalent of

```js
i => i % 2 == 0
```

would be

```js
i => { return i % 2 == 0 }
```

or (in function notation)

```js
function (i) {
  return i % 2 == 0
}
```

Your filter doesn't return the expected result when you use braces because that function doesn't return anything, which means the result is always `undefined`, which is falsy.

#### Why doesn't it work now?

```js
i => { i % 2 == 0 }
```

is equivalent to

```js
function (i) {
  i % 2 == 0
}
```

The function above computes whether `i` can be divided by 2, but it doesn't store or return the value anywhere.